# Runtime Error With Interrupt Timer on Atmega2560

Tags: interrupt, atmega

I'm trying to make a loop execute regularly every 50 milliseconds on an Atmega 2560. Using a simple delay function won't work, because the total loop time ends up being the time it took to execute the other functions in the loop, plus your delay time. This works even less well if your functions calls take variable time, which they usually will.

To solve this, I implemented a simple timer class:

```
volatile unsigned long timer0_ms_tick;
    timer::timer()
    {
        // Set timer0 registers
        TCCR0A = 0b00000000; // Nothing here
        TCCR0B = 0b00000000; // Timer stopped, begin function start by setting last three bits to 011 for prescaler of 64
        TIMSK0 = 0b00000001; // Last bit to 1 to enable timer0 OFV interrupt enable
        sei(); // Enable global interrupts
    }

    void timer::start()
    {
        timer0_ms_tick = 0;

        // Set timer value for 1ms tick (2500000 ticks/sec)*(1 OFV/250 ticks) = 1000OVF/sec
        // 256ticks - 250ticks - 6 ticks, but starting at 0 means setting to 5
        TCNT0 = 5;

        // Set prescaler and start timer
        TCCR0B = 0b00000011;
    }

    unsigned long timer::now_ms()
    {
        return timer0_ms_tick;
    }

    ISR(TIMER0_OVF_vect)
    {
        timer0_ms_tick+=1;
        TCNT0 = 5;
    }
```

The main loop uses this like so:

```
unsigned long startTime, now;
    while(true)
    {
        startTime = startup_timer.now_ms();

        /* Loop Functions */

        // Wait time step
        now = startup_timer.now_ms();
        while(now-startTime < 50)
        {
            now = startup_timer.now_ms();

        }

        Serial0.print(ltoa(now,time_string, 10));
        Serial0.writeChar('-');
        Serial0.print(ltoa(startTime,time_string, 10));
        Serial0.writeChar('=');
        Serial0.println(ltoa(now-startTime,time_string, 10));
    }
```

My output looks like this:

```
11600-11550=50                                                                                                       
11652-11602=50                                                                                                       
11704-11654=50                                                                                                       
11756-11706=50                                                                                                       
12031-11758=273                                                                                                      
11828-11778=50                                                                                                       
11880-11830=50                                                                                                       
11932-11882=50                                                                                                       
11984-11934=50                                                                                                       
12036-11986=50                                                                                                       
12088-12038=50                                                                                                       
12140-12090=50                                                                                                       
12192-12142=50                                                                                                       
12244-12194=50                                                                                                       
12296-12246=50                                                                                                       
12348-12298=50                                                                                                       
12400-12350=50                                                                                                       
12452-12402=50                                                                                                       
12504-12454=50                                                                                                       
12556-12506=50                                                                                                       
12608-12558=50                                                                                                       
12660-12610=50                                                                                                       
12712-12662=50                                                                                                       
12764-12714=50                                                                                                       
12816-12766=50                                                                                                       
12868-12818=50                                                                                                       
12920-12870=50                                                                                                       
12972-12922=50                                                                                                       
13024-12974=50                                                                                                       
13076-13026=50                                                                                                       
13128-13078=50                                                                                                       
13180-13130=50                                                                                                       
13232-13182=50                                                                                                       
13284-13234=50                                                                                                       
13336-13286=50                                                                                                       
13388-13338=50                                                                                                       
13440-13390=50                                                                                                       
13492-13442=50                                                                                                       
13544-13494=50                                                                                                       
13823-13546=277                                                                                                      
13620-13570=50
```

It seems to work well most of the time, but every once in a while something odd will happen with the timing values. I think it has something to do with the interrupt, but I'm not sure what. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Have you got any other interrupts that you are servicing?

Comment: There shouldn't be any other interrupts.